# Laravel array distinct validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-8

I have the following request validation rules in an controller.

```php
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => ['required', 'unique:games,name', 'string'],
            'variant' => ['required', 'string'],
            'rules' => ['string'],
            'is_anonymous' => ['boolean', 'required'],
            'message_mode' => ['required', new EnumRule(MessageModeEnum::class)],
            'powers' => ['required', 'array'],
            'powers.*' => ['distinct:ignore_case', 'required', 'string'],
        ]);

     }
```

Below is the test I'm running against the controller. I would expect the `powers.*` validation to  throw an error as the two powers are equal and not distinct.

```php
     /**
     * @test
     *
     */
    public function endpoint_validation()
    {
        $user = User::factory()->create(['rank' => RankEnum::A()]);
        $response = $this->actingAs($user)->post(route('game.create'), [
            'name' => '::name::',
            'variant' => '::variant::',
            'rules' => '::rules::',
            'is_anonymous' => false,
            'message_mode' => 'none',
            'powers' => [
                '::power::', '::power::'
            ],);
        $response->assertSessionHasErrors('powers');
    }
```

However, this test is failing. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: I have checked on my side, the things are working perfectly

Comment: You said you expect the powers.* validation to throw an error as the two powers are equal and not distinct. and this test is failing. does it mean it did not throw an error?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Should have clarified that. I'm expecting to be the powers array to have no values twice.

Comment: clear one thing that you are sending form request to the controller as in your test case, not JSON request and according to your test case this test case should fail(because of duplicate value) but it actually succeeds which is not the desired test case result.

Comment: and I expect that these are just placeholder '::power::' but actually request they have the actual value like "can destroy the enemy" and so on. If it is true as I checked on my side the things are working and give the proper error message in case if I have duplicate value.

Comment: Yes, I'm sending a form request. However, '::power::' is a general placeholder.
BUT: I am asserting that there is an error on the key 'powers'. The errors are actually assigned to 'powers.0'.

Comment: yes, man! Let understand the validation logic first. In my case, it is also giving me the error on powers.0 because you are sending the array to the form request and according to your validation logic as soon as it passes the "powers" validation logic(i.e required', 'array') it passes to the next array related rule.

Comment: Yes. Before you told me that it worked on your machine I was suspicious that anything could be wrong with my machine. Stupid. I know. Now I inserted 'powers.0' in the assertion and its working fine. Thank!

Comment: I actually check the things on the Postman by sending the request and I was thinking that the validation is not working. anyway happy coding!